# Read dictionary from a file and print the keys

Tags: python, dictionary, key

Basically I am trying to make a code in python that takes a dictionary from a file. It should print the displayed keys.

```
{
    "Name": "namename",
    "Surname": "klsajdak",
    "Mhtrwo": "lsdkaslkd",
    "Phone": ["545454545454", "4554545454545"],
    "Age": 84,
    "kids": {
        "Name": "Zero",
        "Age": 0
    }
}
```

```
my_dict = open("9listes.txt", "r")

for key,value in my_dict.items():
    print("Key : {}".format(key))
```

Comment: This is a basic, basic, like day 1, file i/o issue. You need to read the file after opening it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this via using [`json.load()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load) as:

```
import json

with open('9listes.txt') as f:
    my_dict = json.load(f)   # `my_dict ` is the `dict` you need

    # To print "key" & "value", uncomment below lines:
    # for key, value in my_dict.items():
    #     print("Key: {}, Value: {}".format(key, value))
```

Refer [`json.load()` document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load) for more details.